# Rails Nested Form Sends no Parameters to Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm trying to use `simple_form` and `fields_for` to loop over a collection of objects and create the necessary fields.  However, on submitting the form, no parameters are processed at all to the server. Because of that, I receive a `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` error on submissions.  I've dug a little deeper and inside of the controller and exempted checking for CSRF requests just to hit the strong params method.  Sure enough no parameters from the form were passed in at all.

After bypassing the authenticity check just to see what's going on, I get

```
{"controller"=>"object", "action"=>"update", "format"=>"12"}
```

Looking at the server logs it doesn't pass in any parameters including authenticity tokens, fields, etc. and says

```
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

I've read 422 as per https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2 but I'm not sure why that is the case. Perhaps it's line 3 from below?

This is the markup for the form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@object, url: update_related_object_object_path(@object)) do |f| %>
  <% @object.related_objects.each do |related_object| %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for 'related_objects[]', related_object do |ff| %>
      <%= ff.text_field :prop1 %>
      <%= ff.input_field :prop2 %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  
  <%= f.submit 'Update object' %>
<% end %>
```

This is what the text field looks like:

```
<input type="text" value="Send me please" name="object[related_object][12][prop1]" id="object_related_objects_12_prop1">
```

In the `@object` model, I've allowed for attrs params like this:

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :related_object,
    allow_destroy: true,
    reject_if: :all_blank
```

I've even tried making this an ajax request and the same problem applies.  If I add `remote: true` then checking the params I get the same problem as above.

Comment: Try put this one into your controller skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token

Comment: I tried doing that - it won't send any params.  The reason it fails the auth token check is because the form data which includes that is never sent. I have no idea why though